SDL_Image Fails to Run, Exiting with Code 1
I have an SDL application, which I compile using
g++ -Isrc/include -Lsrc/lib main.cpp -o main -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2_image
It compiles without error, and runs if I do not use any SDL2_Image functions, but as soon as I use those functions, the code will compile, yet fail to run. It does not give any output even if I debug with std::cout or std::cerr. Been debugging for hours, cannot find any solutions, please help.
I tried different lib files for SDL2_image, as well as 32 bit/64 bit binaries. These did not work, and gave the same response.

Try double-clicking the .exe in the explorer, see if it shows any error message.

What do you mean "can't"? You double-click it and nothing happens?

Copied the files onto the Desktop, and ran the executable. Got the error: SDL2_Image.dll was not found.

No, I couldn't run it through VSCode through double clicking, but instead I copied all the files onto desktop to get the error code you're talking about, and that worked to get the error.

Yep, I meant the Windows file explorer, not the VSC tab with the same name.

I moved SDL2_image.dll onto the same directory as SDL2.dll and it worked. Thank you HolyBlackCat all I needed was some kind of error message to get it fixed!
